# VB.net and SFTP to download a file to a client

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sftp

I'm working on an ASP.net web application that is written in VB.net

I need to download a file from the server that the web app is hosted on, to a UNIX client.

What is the best way for me to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup where i simply use the "wget" command.  I also have another system where security is more of an issue, so I wrote a client program in C++ to connect with sockets.

Those are your two major avenues though... unless I'm missing requirements you haven't mentioned...

Comment: Just realized I left out an important piece. The app server is going to be hosted on a Windows system and will need to be able to push a file located on that system to a UNIX system. I'm looking into maybe using PSCP.exe as a process...

Comment: That's a great option if you don't need the security of end-end sockets, but need a secure connection.  As opposed to FTP, your credentials aren't passed in plain text either!  You'll have to do it through command line though...